# Getting from a model's class name to it's type

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember Data and can dynamically find the class name of the model easily enough. For example, if I have a model called `Foobar` and a controller called `FoobarsController` which is an array controller whose `content` property points to the model, I can then:

```
FoobarsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    foobarClassName: function() {
        return this.get('content.typeKey');
    }.property()
}
```

This will result in foobarClassName equaling "App.Foobar". Great. Now what if I want to resolve this back to the model's type, in this case `foobar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea how to do this using an Ember API call so I just created my own *mixin* which gives you a few meta-attributes for a controllers underlying model including my own cunning calculation for the model's "type" (aka, so you can dynamically use this to call the find(type) method amongst other things).

Here's the code:

```
App.ModelMetaMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    _modelProperty: 'content', // the property on the controller to find the bound reference to the model (typically found at 'content')
    modelRef: function() {
        var property = this._modelProperty;
        return this.get(property + '.constructor');
    }.property(this._modelProperty),
    modelName: function() {
        return String(this.get('modelRef'));
    }.property(this._modelProperty),
    modelType: function() {
        var name = this.get('modelName').split('.');
        return Ember.String.camelize(name.pop());
    }.property(this._modelProperty)
}
```

Refer to the `modelType` implementation for my solution to this question. Hope this helps. I'll accept my own answer if I don't get a better one in the next few days.